# Commands in sourced file are not found when executing bash script

Tags: bash, cygwin

My script first sources an API file, the executes a few commands from the file. When the script is executed from the command line, I get "command not found" errors for each of the commands. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
## include API file
source /cygdrive/c/path/to/unifi_sh_api
## login
unifi_login
## authorize a client for 30 minutes, limit down/up speed to 2048/1024kbps, quota is 500MB
unifi_authorize_guest "x2:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" 30 up=1024 down=2048 bytes=500
unifi_logout
```

This returns "command not found" for the 3 unifi_* commands. There are no other errors.

This is on a Windows server and you can see I'm using Cygwin, so maybe that's part of the problem?

Here's what my sourced file looks like, in case the issue is there: https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/4.7.6/unifi_sh_api

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Definitely using bash.

I did try `.` instead of `source` before posting my question here.

Here's the command I'm running in a cmd.exe window:

```
> C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c '/cygdrive/c/path/to/myscript.sh'
```

Comment: Bash is still bash, even when built for Cygwin, so there's no reason this should happen. What if you source the file in an interactive shell?

Comment: Thanks for looking. The result is "'source' is not a recognized command". I'm executing my original script in a cmd.exe window with `> C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c '/cygdrive/c/path/to/myscript.sh'` Maybe it's the mix that's causing problems. Ideally I can use cmd.exe rather than a Cygwin window.

Comment: Are you even sure you're using bash? `source` is a bash builtin, you have a big problem if even builtins aren't recognized. Either you're not using bash (maybe your interactive shell in `/bin/sh`?) or your bash is corrupted. Anyway, try `.` in place of `source`, which is the POSIX way of sourcing. But you still need to get your bash checked.

Comment: The page with the sourced file does not exist. Now the question is unclear.